# Problem with wrapfigure and chemstyle

Tags: wrapfigure, chemstyle

I have a problem with wrapping text around figures. The following example demonstrates the problem, the text is not wrapped around the figure. By disabling the `chemstyle` package, everything works as it should be. However, I am dependent on the `chemstyle` package. Do you know any workaround or why the `chemstyle` package prevents the text to wrap around the included figure?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,captions=nooneline,twoside]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace} 
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry} 

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{chemstyle} 


\begin{document} 

\chapter{Test}


\lipsum[1]
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{figure}
  \end{center}
  \caption{A gull}
\end{wrapfigure}
\lipsum[1]



\end{document}
```

Comment: It does not seem to be `chemstyle` it self but `chemscheme` (which is loaded by `chemstyle`). Just to reduce the MWE even further (note that yuo can replace the image by `\rule{5cm}5cm}`, and it might also be an idea to use a standard class instead of `scrreprt` just ot make sure it is not something from there which is interfering

Comment: We can reduce further, it is not `chemscheme` either, just lost `floatrow`

Comment: @daleif hm sounds like I am in the right place. I ll hope there is a workaround for this problem

Comment: You can search the site for `wrapfig` plus `floatrow`

Comment: What happens for you in your example? For me it semi-works, but with extra white space: The extra space above and below is produced by the center environment. The space on the sides is caused by the chemstyle package (probably the **caption package**) **REDEFINING THE wrapfig environment**, and changing `\textwidth` within it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got no clarification to my question, so I'll assume that MJK's problem was what I saw when I ran the sample.

There are extra spaces above and below the picture caused by the center environment. It should be replaced by a `\centering` command.

The picture is too small because the floatrow package redefines the wrapfigure environment to change the value of `\textwidth` into the width of the figure. It does so for all figure types, which is confusing in twocolumn documents! (In the question, the width `0.5\textwidth` would be bad in a twocolumn document also.)

Living with floatrow.sty's funny `\textwidth` means avoiding it and using more appropriate line width parameters.

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\columnwidth}
  \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.95\linewidth]{figure}
  \caption{A gull}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround, with the `\InsertBoxR` command from the plain TeX macro package. This command takes two mandatory arguments: the number of lines at the beginning of the paragraph that remain unshortened, and the box to be inserted, and one optional argument (at the end!) – the number of supplementary lines to be shortened, in case IeX does not calculate the correct number of shorter lines. It does not seem to conflict with `chemstyle`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,captions=nooneline,twoside]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemstyle}
\input{insbox.tex}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test}

\lipsum[1]

\InsertBoxR{2}{%
\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{\raggedleft\includegraphics[width=0.48\textwidth]{TasmanianDevil}\\
\captionof{figure}{The Tasmanian Devil}}
}[5]
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]